# It cannot find the correct email address in the database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to check for a valid email address and then see if the email address is in the database. At the moment the validation for a valid email address works fine. But if I enter in an email address which is in the database such as "nickfrosty@yahoo.com", instead of echoing the message `You have entered in the Correct Email Address`, it echos the complete opposite message and echos `You entered in the Wrong Email Address`. So this is making me think that it cannot find the email address in the database even though I am sure the email address is in the database.

So my question is that why can't it find the email address in the database and hence echos the message that I have entered in the wrong email address?

Below is the code (mysqli/php):

```
if ( (strlen($email) >= 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) && (strstr($email, ".")) ){

echo "You have entered in the Correct Email Address";

}
else{
echo "You entered in the Wrong Email Address";
}
```

Comment: You need to add error handling and echo out variables along the way; what does `$numrows` contain, what does `$row` contain, etc.

Comment: You're not "finding an email in database" in you code, you're "finding the email of a specified user in database" and see if that email matches your input. An email exists in database doesn't mean it should belongs to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT TeacherUsername, TeacherEmail FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ?";
```

means you check the input against `TeacherUsername`, not `TeacherEmail`. You might want to try

```
$query = "SELECT TeacherUsername, TeacherEmail FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherEmail = ?";
```