# wrong echo is being outputted from if statement

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It cannot find the correct email address in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182225/it-cannot-find-the-correct-email-address-in-the-database)

I have a problem with my if else statement. When I Type in the correct username and email in the textboxes, it keeps going on to the else statement and echos "You entered in the Wrong Email Address" rather than performing the if statement and echoing "Your details are correct". Does anyone know why it is echoing the wrong statement even though I have entered in the correct username and correct email associated with that user from the database?

```
if (isset($_POST['resetbtn'])) {
    //get form data
    $user  = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //make sure info is provided
    if ($user) {
        if ($email) {
            if ((strlen($email) >= 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) && (strstr($email, "."))) {

                $query   = "SELECT TeacherUsername, TeacherEmail FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ?";
                // prepare query
                $stmt    = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                // You only need to call bind_param once
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
                // execute query
                $stmt->execute();
                // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
                $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername, $dbTeacherEmail);
                //get number of rows
                $stmt->store_result();
                $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

                if ($numrows == 1) {

                    $row            = $stmt->fetch();
                    $dbTeacherEmail = $row['TeacherEmail'];

                    //make sure email is correct

                    if ($email == $dbTeacherEmail) {

                        echo "Your details are correct";
                    } else {
                        echo "You entered in the Wrong Email Address";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Please Enter in your Email";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Please Enter in your Username";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off validating the email using [PHP Validate Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) which might well solve your problem of hitting the wrong if selection.

Comment: What are the values of `$email` and `$dbTeacherEmail` when you execute the code? I'll bet dollars to donuts that they're different.

Comment: try echoing both variables before the comparison to make sure of their values

Comment: Also, you can collapse the three `if` statements on top into one.

Comment: If the database returns a matching row, you shouldn't need to test if the email address is the same. You've already authenticated. Don't give an unauthorized user a hint that they've entered a correct username, and an incorrect password (or vice versa). That just tells them that they stumbled upon a correct value and now they only have one other value to "hack".

Comment: Why not just compare the username and email in the `SELECT`? This way, if you return a row, you know that the information entered was valid. No need to check with PHP, no need to let the user know which field was correct. It's more secure this way.

Comment: @Matt OK what is happening is that if I echo both `$email` and `$dbTeacherEmail`, then it echos the email entered in the textbox for `$email` but it echos nothing for `$dbTeacherEmail`

Comment: @Matt It was because I was watching a tutorial on this in youtube and the person did it this way, except difference is that his is mysql and mine is mysqli

Comment: @Matt I will do it by the SELECT statement way which you told me where I compare username and email by SELECT statement but I am encountering a different problem. I will need to change my question if that is ok? Plz comment back, same for everybody else looking at this question if it is ok if I update my question.

Comment: @user1646293 update away! I'm sure we all want to help. :-) Just be sure to comment back to us when you're finished updating.

Comment: @Matt it is ok problem is solved, I realise there is a problem with university server so it doesn't allow me to send emails through the server yet. But your comment on comparing username and email through SELECT statement has fixed this problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For comparing strings in php do not use ==.

Use

```
strcmp($string1,$string2)==0
```

to test equality.

Comment: Actually, `==` is just as valid if you just want to test for equality.

Comment: Hmm it appears you are correct. This I was not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `$stmt->fetch()` incorrectly. You seem to be treating the return value as an array, but the return is a boolean, and the value of `$dbTeacherEmail` is already bound to the result by `$stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername, $dbTeacherEmail)`.

Try removing the line that reads

```
$dbTeacherEmail = $row['TeacherEmail'];
```

and see if you get what you want. Also see the docs on [mysqli-stmt::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)